# Установка модуля vosk

Tags: python, github, pip, vosk, pep

При установке библиотеки Vosk вышла данная ошибка:

> DEPRECATION: srt is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enfo
> rce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559

Зашел в гитхаб и посмотрел, ничем не помогло я так и не понял как правильно установить Vosk, при попытке запуска программы выходит ошибка

> OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jarvis\ven\lib\site-packages\vosk\libvosk.dll': error 0x7e

Пробовал установить Vosk в не виртуальной среде но Python его попросту не видит, так-же пробовал все что указано на их официальном сайте https://alphacephei.com/vosk/ никак не могу установить, пожалуйста помогите буду очень благодарен, спасибо вам большое

Comment: «the 'wheel' package is not installed» — вот с этим разберитесь, пакет wheel обычно всегда должен быть установлен

Comment: Может так pip install vosk --use-pep517 -U

Comment: не помогает ничего, попробую завтра один метод, если решу то скажу